# How to set value to RadioButtonList Item in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList that includes 2 values - "Yes" and "no". I want that everytime a user gets into the form page, the value will be set as the one he chose when he filled the form in the first time. I have no problem doing it with the TextBoxes, only with the RadioButtonList.
Here are the codes:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

the Code behind:
(the 'if' checks in the DB if the user chose the "No" Radio button when he first filled the form, the ??? is what I need from you :))

```
            if ((String)cmd3.ExecuteScalar() == "No")
        {
            ???
        }
```

I tried `RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue("No").Selected = true;` but it did'nt work.

Let me know if I wasn't clear, and Thanks. Idan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
 if ((String)cmd3.ExecuteScalar() == "No")
 {
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex  = 1;
 }
 else
 {
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex  = 0;
 }
```